# Calling Variable Class / Method Programmatically

Tags: php

I have a method in a variable named class that I need to call dynamically, how can I call this:

```
$foo = "object"
```

Where object is a specific class

How do I call this in PHP?

```
$foo::method()
```

Comment: could not understand your question exactly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of the question is confusing but from what I understand, if you want to set `$foo` to a specific class, lets call it `Foo` you can do this:

```
$foo = new Foo;
```

Here is our class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
  public $aMemberVar = 'aMemberVar Member Variable';
  public $aFuncName = 'aMemberFunc';   

  function aMemberFunc() {
     print 'Inside `aMemberFunc()`';
    }
 }
```

If you want to access a class variable `Foo` and set it to a variable you can do this:

```
 $myVar = 'aMemberVar';
 print $foo->$myVar //prints "aMemberVar Member Variable"
```

Also to clarify `$foo::method()` implies that `$foo` is a static class, and static classes cannot be instantiated but they can call on its class method `method()` by using the scope resolution operator (`::`)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$$foo::method();
```

See [PHP variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)